# Connecting Windows 7 computer to wireless printer

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, printer

I have an Acer Aspire 5532 laptop and am trying to get it to recognize the Canon mp970 printer to print wirelessly. Our mac automatically made the connection. The laptop is running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Canon PIXMA MP970 website download selection](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=DownloadDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=334&modelid=15481) and select "Windows 7" as your operating system.

[image: Screenshot]

You'll see two setup files you can download, as well as the PDF setup guides.

Answer (score 0):

use the Canon installation disc.

it should include a Wireless Connection Wizard.